# Jetty server running in cygwin terminal does not terminate by CTRL + c

Tags: java, ant, jetty

I am starting jetty server in cygwin terminal using an ant target.
But when I try to stop that server using CTRL + c, I get command line in cygwin but server process still there running at background. Please any buddy help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my ant target.

```
<target name="startJetty" depends="readProps">
       <java jar="${deploy.home}/jetty/start.jar" fork="true" dir="${deploy.home}/jetty">
         <sysproperty key="app.home" value="${deploy.home}"/>
         <sysproperty key="DEBUG" value="1"/>
       </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `fork="true"` would prevent the Jetty PID from being in the foreground, necessary to actually send the `SIGINT` signal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) to Jetty.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I changed fork="false" but it is throwing exception when building the project. Following is the exception -

Caught: : Cannot execute a jar in non-forked mode. Please set fork='true'.